# Why my navigation arrows are hiding the text in the background?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

I have this in my activity's xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/jokeIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jokeIcon" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/allJokesTxt"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:padding="16dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/jokeprev"
        android:src="@drawable/backarrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/jokenext"
        android:src="@drawable/nextarrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I have 2 imageviews at the bottom. The problem is that the 2 arrows are overlaping the scrollview content. and it looks like this:

[image: screen]

I will place the proper arrow size, but at this point the arrows are just overlapping the scrollView.

I know that I miss something really small here and that I miss some basics on the xml design. Can you give me a push?

Comment: Add android:layout_above="@+id/jokeprev" to your scrollview

Comment: @PedroOliveira I knew that I miss a small part here. Can you answer it, so I will be able to accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the scrollview is set to fill the parent. That's why the buttons will overlap the scrollview. The trick is to add

```
android:layout_above="@+id/jokeprev
```

to the scrollview. This way the scrollview will be allways above the buttons.

Glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative layout, so the components are superposed.
Do something like this :

```
<linearLayout   android:orientation="vertical"
     ...
     ... >

    <ImageView>
       ...
       ... 
    </ImageView>

    <ScrollView   android:layout_weight="1"
       ...
       ... >
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout  android:orientation="horizontal" 
       ...
       ... >
          <ImageView LEFT  />

          <ImageView RIGHT />

   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```